# unable to know how to get the value from tree

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm writing an XSL and below is my requirement.

1. When ever I come across a `superscript`, search the entire XML and see a listitem with attribute override and hte value should be equal to the `superscript`.
2. if it is found apply templates on the same

Below is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<division>
<superscript>1</superscript> 
<page num="1"/>
        <note role="para-footnote">
            <orderedlist>
             <listitem override="1">
                        <para>Hi</para>
             </listitem>
            </orderedlist>
        </note>     
</division>
```

And here is my XSL

```
   <xsl:template match="superscript[name(ancestor::*[last()]) = 'division']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//listitem[@override=.]/preceding::page[1]" mode="first"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cnt" select="count(preceding::superscript)+1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="varHeaderNote" select='concat("f",$cnt)'/>
        <xsl:variable name="varFootNote" select='concat("#ftn.",$cnt)'/>
        <sup>
            <a name="{$varHeaderNote}" href="{$varFootNote}" class="tr_ftn">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </a>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
        <xsl:variable name="pb" select="./@num"/>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pb"/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
        <a name="{concat('pg_',$pb)}"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

my current O/p

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<hmtl>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>New Version!</title>
   </head>
   <sup><a name="f1" href="#ftn.1" class="tr_ftn">1</a></sup> 
   <page num="1"></page>
    <note role="para-footnote">
      <orderedlist>
         <listitem override="1">
            <para>Hi</para>
         </listitem>
      </orderedlist>
   </note>      
</hmtl>
```

Expected O/p:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<hmtl>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>New Version!</title>
   </head>
 <?pb label='1'?>
   <sup><a name="f1" href="#ftn.1" class="tr_ftn">1</a></sup> 
   <page num="1"></page>
    <note role="para-footnote">
      <orderedlist>
         <listitem override="1">
            <para>Hi</para>
         </listitem>
      </orderedlist>
   </note>      
</hmtl>
```

Here is a working fiddle. http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGR

Please let me know where Am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `@override = current()` in the predicate, see http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGR/1.

Or better define a key `<xsl:key name="li" match="listitem" use="@override"/>` and then you can use `key('li', .)` to find the `listitem` referenced by the `superscript`.

Comment: Hi Friend, thanks, this is working awesome :-), but a small question, is not `.` same as `current()`?

Comment: Inside the predicate not, no, with `//listitem[@override=.]` the `.` is the `listitem` you have applied the predicate to so you are basically comparing the `@override` attribute of the `listitem` element to the (string value of the) listitem itself. `current()` refers to the current context item, as defined in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-function.